# Loss function to maximize sum of targets

Tags: regression, classification, neural-networks, loss-functions

I have a dataset {$X_i$, $Y_i$}. $Y_i$ - real value targets, they can be negative. The task is to teach classifier $f: X_i \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ to maximize the sum below
$$
L(f) = \sum_i f(X_i) * Y_i
$$
So $f(X_i) = I[Y_i > 0]$ would be the ideal classifier. 
I'm looking for appropriate smooth loss function to teach NN. NN output is probability $p(X_i)$, so $f(X_i) = I[p(X_i) > 0.5]$. I have tried the next loss function:
$$
BadLoss(p) = \sum_i p(X_i) * Y_i
$$
but because $Y_i$ can be negative it is bad-defined loss and NN converges to nothing good. The best results I got were with usual logloss:
$$
Loss(p) = \sum_i logloss(p(X_i), \; I[Y_i > 0])
$$

Can be there better loss functions to maximize the sum $L(f)$?

Comment: As you mention, the ideal classifier should output 1 when Y is positive. Logistic/softmax output layer w/ log loss is pretty much standard for binary classification with NNs. So, the last setup you mention (using log loss) sounds pretty good. You could try using a linear output layer to predict Y itself, using squared error as the loss function (i.e. use NN for regression). Then, output 1 if the predicted value is positive. Not sure whether this would give any improvement.

Comment: @user20160 Regression worked much worser. Is there a way to transform loss L(f) to smooth loss which I can optimize directly?

Comment: One thing to notice is that the magnitude of $Y_i$ determines how much example $i$ contributes to the final objective function $L$. E.g. misclassifying an example with small $Y$ has little effect and misclassifying an example with large $Y$ has a greater effect. Standard, unweighted loss functions wouldn't capture this. Whatever loss function you choose for the NN, you could try using a weighted version, where the weight of the $i$th example is $|Y_i|$. E.g. try weighted version of log loss, etc.